# QLPreviewController is not saving large sized PDF

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, qlpreviewcontroller

I am using QLPreviewController with SwiftUI using UIViewControllerRepresentable.
If I try to delete or insert pages of large size PDF, QLPreviewController is not calling delegate methods (didUpdateContentsOf, didSaveEditedCopyOf).

```
struct QuickLookController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    weak var delegate: QLPreviewControllerDelegate?
    weak var dataSource: QLPreviewControllerDataSource?

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UINavigationController {
        
        let controller = context.coordinator.controller
        
        controller.delegate = delegate
        controller.dataSource = dataSource
        controller.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = context.coordinator.dismissButton
        
        return UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ viewController: UINavigationController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<QuickLookController>) { }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Self.Coordinator {
        .init(parent: self)
    }
    
    @MainActor
    class Coordinator: NSObject {
                
        var parent: QuickLookController
        
        init(parent: QuickLookController) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        lazy var controller: QLPreviewController = {
            let controller = QLPreviewController()
            return controller
        }()
        
        lazy var dismissButton: UIBarButtonItem = {
            let button = UIBarButtonItem(
                title: NSLocalizedString("Done", comment: ""),
                style: .plain,
                target: self,
                action: #selector(rightButtonTapped(_:))
            )
            button.tag = 2
            
            return button
        }()
        
        @objc func rightButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
            controller.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Delegate

```
extension ViewerModel: QLPreviewControllerDataSource, QLPreviewControllerDelegate {
    
    public func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
        1
    }
    
    public func previewController(
        _ controller: QLPreviewController,
        previewItemAt index: Int
    ) -> QLPreviewItem {

        let title = self.document
            .documentURL?
            .lastPathComponent ?? ""
        
        let url = PDFManager
            .directory
            .appendingPathComponent(title) as NSURL
        
        return url as QLPreviewItem
    }

    public func previewControllerDidDismiss(_ controller: QLPreviewController) {

    }
    
    public func previewControllerWillDismiss(_ controller: QLPreviewController) {

    }
  
    ✔️ Even if I set "updateContents" it is same
    public func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, editingModeFor previewItem: QLPreviewItem) -> QLPreviewItemEditingMode {
        .createCopy
    }

    ✔️ Controller is not calling method when PDF is large
    public func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, didUpdateContentsOf previewItem: QLPreviewItem) {

    }

    ✔️ Controller is not calling method when PDF is large
    public func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, didSaveEditedCopyOf previewItem: QLPreviewItem, at modifiedContentsURL: URL) {
        
    }
}
```

I tried to call delegate method programmatically, but I can't get url of modified PDF.